# Retrieve single term slug

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I'm creating common "Single Tag Page" for different Post Types.
I'm using next code:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'any', 'tag' => single_term_title( '', false ), 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="entry-content">
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>
```

It works fine until there is no taxonomy terms conflict.
For example:
If I have Category & Tag names - **"Videos"**, Category will have slug - *"/videos"* & Tag *"/videos-2"*.

In case when slug isn't the same as taxonomy name above code does not working.
I need an alternative function for **single_term_title()**, something like **"single_term_slug()"**.

Any ideas?

P.S. I was thinking about "[**get_term_by()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)" function, but I didn't had luck to adopt it to the code above.

**Updated:** I've posted my code below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you guys for such quick response. Much appreciated!

Here is code for "global" Tags page (displaying terms of default 'post_tag' taxonomy):

```
<?php
$term_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
    if ( !$term_slug )
    return;
    else  
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'any', 'tag' => $term_slug, 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>
```

And the next code example is for custom taxonomy query (displaying terms of custom taxonomy):

```
<?php 
//http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters
$term_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;
        if ( !$term_slug )
        return;
        else
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
                     array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'gallery_category',
                       'field' => 'slug',
                       'terms' => $term_slug,
                       'posts_per_page' => 10
                     )
                   )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>
```

Comment: Is this your answer to your own question, or a follow up part of your question?

Comment: This seems to me like an answer in context of original question, dismissing the flag on it.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - This is my answer. I've posted whole solution code.
#1 is for displaying terms of default 'post_tag' taxonomy, which is used in custom post types.
#2 is for displaying terms of custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reference to the term object in `$wp_query`, and a shortcut function to grab this (providing you are running WordPress 3.1): `get_queried_object()`.

So, to get the slug you would do `echo get_queried_object()->slug;`

If you are not running WordPress 3.1, you will have to call the `get_queried_object()` on the `global $wp_query`:

`global $wp_query;`
`echo $wp_query->get_queried_object()->slug;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a forked `single_term_slug()` function out of [single_term_title()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L732)

```
function single_term_slug( $prefix = '', $display = true ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    if ( !$term )
    return;
    if ( is_category() )
        $term_slug = apply_filters( 'single_cat_slug', $term->slug );
    elseif ( is_tag() )
        $term_slug = apply_filters( 'single_tag_slug', $term->slug );
    elseif ( is_tax() )
        $term_slug = apply_filters( 'single_term_slug', $term->slug );
    else
        return;
    if ( empty( $term_slug ) )
        return;
    if ( $display )
        echo $prefix . $term_slug;
    else
        return $term_slug;
}
```